# Hide and show text with the caret class

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'd like to show a subset of text from a description field, then toggle the full text when a caret is clicked.

My current approach, which is close to what I would like to have:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" class="dropdown-toggle">
  </a>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <p class="card-subtitle text-muted"><%= @foo[:description] %></p>
  </div>
  <p class="card-subtitle text-muted text-truncate"><%= @foo[:description] %></p>
</div>
```

Issues:

- Is there a way to get the caret to pivot 90 degrees when it shows/hides the content?
- Is there a way to hide the truncated text when the full text is shown?
- Is there a way to have the caret displayed immediately to the left of the text, rather than above it?

Comment: in looking deeper my previous suggestions don't really apply.  Short answer is yes it can be done with some JS/JQ. the trick is finding the right mix BS Components and css.  I'm curious now and must play :)

Answer (score 1):

So, given that...

- Your html markup is a `card-body` but since
- all you really want to do is to reveal the full card body text and since
- carets no longer seem to be defined as a standalone helper in BS4

then

- You really don't want or need the collapse component since you don't *really* want the collapsed element to be gone, just reduced to 1 line of truncated, ellipsed text
- I substituted a font awesome caret for the apparently deprecated BS4 caret
- I use css and JQ to perform the caret rotate and card body text reveal

---

#### Edit: animating flex

There are all kinds of issues when animating to/from the `text-truncate` class.

The [cleanest option I found](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/#article-header-id-6) (thanks to [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com)) animates a flex container. The entire article is an interesting read, learned much, so I reworked my original answer.

I have no idea if this will break BS4, but as Cards are flex based to begin with...I don't know, but it should be interesting.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $(this).find('i.caret').toggleClass('cw-90');
    $('div.card-text.collapsible').toggleClass('collapsed');
  });

});
```

```css
.fa-caret-right {
  transition: all 250ms;
}

.cw-90 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.card-body {
  display: inherit;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: inherit;
  height: 200px;
}

.collapsible {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: flex 1s ease-out;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 1rem;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  flex: 1;
}

.collapsed {
  flex: 0;
}

.collapsible.collapsed p {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.collapsible:not(.collapsed) p {
  overflow: auto;
  text-overflow: auto;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <a href="#" role="button">LinkButton<i class="ml-1 caret fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
    <div class="card-text border rounded p-2 collapsible collapsed">
      <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```